# Error: No such module 'XCTest' when building iOS project

Tags: swift, xcode, unit-testing, xctest

I am using XCTest for unit testing in my iOS project in Xcode. When I try to build my project, I receive this error message:

> No such module 'XCTest'

I have already verified that `XCTest.framework` is included in the "Link Binary With Libraries" section of my target's build phases.

I have tried the following troubleshooting steps without success:

- Cleaning the build folder and rebuilding the project.
- Verifying that XCTest is correctly imported in my test files (`import XCTest`).
- Ensuring that my project's target includes XCTest as a dependency.

Despite these efforts, I am still encountering the error.
Can someone please provide guidance on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: i solved it with this incase anyone comes across the same issue am on xcode 15.2 https://earltedly.github.io/posts/no-such-module-xctest/ enable this SYSTEM_FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS=YES in your target Build settings

Comment: That goes in the Answer field.

Comment: idk where that is...am kinda new to stackoverflow am in no rush to learn but thanks for the tip....i found it

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with this in case anyone comes across the same issue. I am on xcode 15.2.

Based on the information in [this link](https://earltedly.github.io/posts/no-such-module-xctest), set:

`SYSTEM_FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS=YES`

in your target's Build settings

Answer (score -1):

have you try also to close xcode and open again? sometimes happens

Comment: if not try to delete and adding it again, making sure you selected the target, also try command B

Comment: i did, but nothing seemed to work i followed all online examples but this was the only one that worked...the solution i found was incase all the others didn't work...thanks though

Comment: This is not an answer, this should go in the comments.